# What kind of email address should I use in CV?

Tags: resume, email

I have read ["What should a professional email address look like?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/what-should-a-professional-email-address-look-like). My problem is somewhat similar to this but not all.

At first when I was creating my gmail username (age of 15) I got frustrated with already taken usernames and made a terrible long username like `<my last name>.<my first name><10 digit mobile number>@gmail.com`. It didn't seem ugly then but after getting into college and knowing that bad email id make a bad impression in CV made me think.

So I made a new id (age of 19) looks like `<my last name>.<my first name>atwork@gmail.com`. Now I have two problems. Should I put both email id in CV or just one? Does the later one sound too formal; it literally have `atwork` in middle?

Comment: How would someone reading your CV distinguish between these addresses in terms of which to use? Phone numbers may be categorized as home and cell in some signatures that could appear on CVs and other documents but do you have a similar distinction for these addresses?

Comment: I think you need to say why you are considering including both for answers to address that fully. Do you have a specific reason to include both (other than 'I can't decide')?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should a professional email address look like?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/what-should-a-professional-email-address-look-like)

Comment: I'd suggest you purchase a domain name.  Just to be able to use it for email is very cheap. No need for a full fledged website, just the name and a redirect to one of your emails will do. I picked up a couple of professional looking domain names for something like $20 - $30 a year.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't imagine any situation where it would make sense to put multiple email addresses in a CV. The last thing you want your CV to do is cause confusion or frustration in people who wish to contact you. Do not put them in the position of wondering which email address they should use, or whether they should use both.

As for which one you should use - I think you're over-thinking it if you're worrying about the difference between `name.10 digit number` and `name.atwork`. Assuming you're distributing your CV electronically, anyone who needs to email you is going to click or cut & paste anyway, they're not going to have to type out that 10-digit number.

The one circumstance when I would suggest paying attention to your email address is if you had something that could come across and genuinely unprofessional: `sexxxxy`, `xXxSaTaNxXx`, `weedlord420`, that sort of thing. Don't put that in your CV. Just don't.

Comment: Although `weedlord420` may be acceptable in some contexts (since that seems to be legal now in some states). Equivalently, if you're working as in a gentleman's club, having your e-mail address being `sexxxxy` may not be a limiting factor. But if it's for a 'normal' job, probably best to avoid them as @Carson says.

Answer (score 5):

For me, having a separate email for work / professional stuffs is important.

1. have a more professional looking email address instead of sexyHot87@hotmail.com, hotblazer@gmail.com etc etc. instead put your name such as Steve.Jobs@gmail.com etc etc.
2. Seperate the mails you receive. This is because i get alot of junk / personal mails and sometimes important mail such as job offers are being overlooked and discarded.

Do not put more that 1 email address or more than 1 mobile number as it confuses the person handling it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a professional sounding email address for job applications for eg: J.Bloggs@hotmail.com rather than hex673bd@hotmail.com.  Try to avoid using your full name so identity theft is made harder.

When job hunting your likely to get a lot of SPAM emails from job websites that aren't relative to your job search (Monster, Jobsite.co.uk).  I recommend that you setup a email alias so that you can kill the email address once you complete your job search and not have to block emails for months on end.  You can also then use a email rule to filter the email alias incoming messages into a specific folder called 'Jobs'.  A email alias is a alternative email address that directs mail to your normal inbox, for eg: test1@hotmail.com and test2@hotmail.com may both go to the same inbox but use different alias addresses.  Hotmail (Outlook.com) includes both the rule and alias features you will need.

Answer (score -1):

Take a simple username that is just your . and add 123 or your date and month of birth. You can have multiple email addresses and forward them all to your "main" address and set which account to reply from. This way you get all your email in one inbox. Tweak around in the GMail account settings for it.

Comment: With the amount of social engineering going on I can't advise ANYONE to put their date of birth in their email address.