# Using nickname as e-mail address

Tags: email

i've already read a few threads regarding a professional e-mail address. I'm looking forward to make a simple e-mail with general usage including also finding a job. I use only android phone, chrome and stuff for which I need a gmail account (i know of the google $10 every year service)

My point is : i have John Doe (my name is very common), AND some variant of it are taken, or all.

I want to use not only gmail but also want to create my identity on the internet so that if someone is looking for my "nickname", they'll find what i "made" them find.

Practical example of what i mean by nickname (if possible to make it), i would still like to use some parts of my name in my email address, so as nickname i'd either use a kinda obvious anagram but with an extra suffix or prefix, such as "Doejorks"(lets pretend this isnt taken), or either "MkJodon".

Would something like this, an anagram, or a mod of my name look not professional? If some of you are also gamers, i would aswell maybe use that name in games, and if results pop up in google i wouldn't mind probably, since i want to be accepted for who i am and not fake my interests or fake my person.

If not this, what else could i try? I've read that adding birth's year is bad, so i would avoid that. But the whole point of this question is if using a nickname that is sort of related to my real name and surname (anagram or mix etc) looks bad.

I may see the pro in this that if they look up my nickname they'll find all relevant information about me, for which I will be careful :)

PS  : I know the alternative solution of using domain name, using another domain with johndoe@anotherdomain, but my question here is, i repeat formulated towards what i just meant.

Now that I think about it, while i'm at it, I would say that using a total random nickname is a bad idea or it is no different than an anagram of name/surname, if that doesnt sound pretty much like your name?

Please let me know what I can do, I'm looking forward into making a new facebook account and twitter and such but I don't know how to make my email address, i dont know what to do and I dont know if i care too much about it (unless its, as ive read one milion time sexydude69@mail.com, which i obviously wont so **this is not what i mean by nickname!**)

Thanks!!! I hope this thread can also help more people that will google for this sentence, i tried to pick a good one

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question currently linked so much as [this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/what-should-a-professional-email-address-look-like).

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to get a domain of your own, and set up a professional email under that.  AonnaSmith@AonnaSmith.me  (For demonstration purposes, only).

You can't swing a dead cat online without hitting a domain registrar that would do this very inexpensively.

Comment: To be honest, repeating the full name before and after the @ looks weird. I would use for *contact@...* instead.

Comment: Or john@johndoe.com or similar could work. With a common name the trick is finding the domain.