# Choosing professional name for mail address when the domain is "NameSurname.xxx"

Tags: email

I am struggling to find the perfect form for my mail address when I have the domain => NameSurname.fr

I currently have NameSurname@icloud.com and NameSurname@gmail.com but in my need to have something more "credible" I would like to use my domain name... however, the "basics" like "Hello@..."; "Me@..." or "Postmaster/Webmaster@..." doesn't look very professional to me.

Any advices on how to do it correctly ?

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11731/2322

Comment: Having a .xxx suffix website isn't professional unless you are in the porn industry ;)

Comment: Personally on all my domains I use `me@[domainname]`, as they *already know* it's you.

Comment: I use just the first letter of my first name as my default (ie. j@johndoe.com). That way, the address is as short and simple as possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have a site like this.  Just **first name** for main address.

Having both names is kind of repetitive therefore pretentious (unless your name is really really long and you include your middle name - then it might be funny).  Having admin/webmaster/postmaster makes people think they are emailing you about a problem on your website.

john@johndoe.com relays I am talking to John on John's website.  It is easy for users to figure this out, nothing negative about it, and separates your email from admin type tasks.  I would email john@johndoe.com to tell him that his article was great, and admin@johndoe.com to tell him that the main menu isn't working right on tablets.

Only if you are this weight lifter from Madagascar can you use your full name.

harinelinanathaliarakotondramanana@harinelinanathaliarakotondramanana.xxx

Comment: No. No. No! Tell the guy from Madagascar to get familiar with this link:  http://scr.im/ We can't let him kill us with an email this long :)

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan - Look at you displaying your gender bias.  :)  The weightlifter is a SHE!  http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/athletes/ra/nathalia-rakotondramanana-1.html

Comment: On a variation to reduce repetition you might try initials for the username part of the address. For example, if your name is Max Mustermann then you could make your e-mail address in the form mm@maxmustermann.xyz

Answer (score 5):

I would like to make another suggestion: "mail@NameSurname.fr".

Reason: Because of the meaning of the at symbol this e-mail address reads as "mail at ..." what sounds kind of natural to me.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I use COMPANY_IM_TALKING_TO@mydomain.com

If I were to send a resume to Google, my email would be Google@RobP.com - if I were to apply to Yahoo, it would be Yahoo@RobP.com

Internally, it all goes to my primary mailbox; but this allows me to do all sorts of filtering and gives me more control over my mail.  For example, when I start getting spam mail, I can quickly see where it originated from because every e-mail address has a one to one relationship with companies or websites.

Comment: Sounds like something that might be misconstrued as a phishing attempt.

Comment: @Raystafarian - I consider that a bonus.  Any company that I'm corresponding with in a professional context that would mistake this as a phishing attempt is a company I'd like to avoid in the future.

Comment: I meant in terms of hitting an automated filter. This is, of course, if you're just emailing and not using an application system.

Comment: I would think it was a bit freaky if someone set up an email address with my company name in to contact me. If someone didn't know your reasoning it could be considered as a mis-representation

Comment: @MattP he doesn't set up an email address. He owns the RobP.com domain. Any email sent to his domain will go to his main email account. You can email him right now at fakeSite@robp.com and he will get it, even though he never "set up" an email account for fakeSite.

Comment: @basher your average hiring manager probably doesn't know or care about what settings you have on your domain to get email. If you sent me, and expected me to respond to, a message from sethr@basher.com, I would think it very strange. It makes it feel like I'm talking to myself, or someone impersonating me.

Comment: @SethR - you can use 'CorrespondenceWithSethr@whatever.com' or 'EmailsWithSethr@whatever.com' or 'InterviewWithGoogle@whatever.com' or '2016InterviewWithGoogle@whatever.com'

Answer (score 0):

Another choice would be your initials.  `ns@NameSurname.fr` or if your middle name is Middle `nms@NameSurname.fr`.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use my domain name... however, the "basics" like
>   "Hello@..."; "Me@..." or "Postmaster/Webmaster@..." doesn't look very
>   professional to me.
>
> Any advices on how to do it correctly ?

The best ways I've seen it done would be to use your firstname or nickname.

firstname@NameSurname.fr

or

nickname@NameSurname.fr

Only do this if you have a reasonably typical nickname. (For example, I would use something Joe@JosephStrazzere.fr but probably not Wacko@JoeStrazzere.fr)