# Is this email address a good idea?

Tags: professionalism, resume, email

I am setting up my portfolio site and with it I want to have some professional email.
Many domains are already taken but I found *firstNameLastName*.com available.

This is problem though because originally I wanted to my email look like: *firstName*@*lastName*.com

So my question is: Is email@*firstNameLastName*.com is a good idea?

Thank you

---

P.S.: I heard that I shouldn't use any other suffix other than .com. Is that true? Because otherwise I could use *lastName*.net

Comment: Your email address does not really matter. What matters is the content of the email.

Comment: Also see http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/what-should-a-professional-email-address-look-like?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any suffix you want, .net, .company, .com , .info etc,. Whatever domain name you have.

If the .net works for you, get it.

Comment: There's also a .name domain which looks nice and is quite underused: you might still be able to snag yours!