# Domain email vs. Public email

Tags: professionalism, email

When starting a new company with a website, is it more professional to use an email in the format email@mydomain.com rather than email@gmail.com? 
Why would it make a difference?
I took a look at the post found [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/what-should-a-professional-email-address-look-like) so now I know what to put before the @ sign, but I'd like to know which domain to use.

Comment: You can use gmail as your domain email source. But, I think your company should have a distinct company email name. Going with Google risks (1) looking rinky-dink (small time), and (2) what do you do when (ok, if) you become successful - do you still use Gmail for everyone?

Comment: If ease of usage suggests Gmail to you why not setup a mail server on your domain and have the address redirect to gmail.  That way you get the appearance of a larger organization.

Comment: We used to laugh out loud in the early 2000's when someone handed out a business card with an AOL.com address on it.  What do you think people will think of you if you hand them a "Zabari09394@Gmail.com" business card today?

Comment: I can promise you it is not worth having email not the same as your business, so yes it is professional to have your email as your domain.

Comment: @gnat I checked that one out, it's not really related

Comment: Do you have a public Web site like mycompany.example.com ? If so, then your e-mail addresses really out to have the form foo@mycompany.example.com. Whether you use Gmail or someone else to provide the underlying e-mail service is not so important.

Comment: Seriously, the indicated duplicate is no duplicate. That question is about an person with an resume, this question is about a business.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a business using email on your own domain is basically a requirement. No one is going to take you seriously if you're using a free email account to run your business.

If you like the ease-of-use of Gmail, and want their spam protection and other features, you can get Google Apps and use your domain in Gmail: https://apps.google.com

Don't setup forwarders or anything like that, because when you reply it's going to show as coming from your Gmail account. It's $5/user/month to do it right.

Answer (score 4):

So you have a company and a domain name but you want to use gmail.

You will look like you are not a company and do not have a domain name.
Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Other people have answered this question, but not in a broad enough sense.

If you purchase a domain from a domain registrar, you can host it and have email associated with that domain name.  For example, you purchase `mydomain.com`.  You can have a website at `www.mydomain.com` and have email addresses like `me@mydomain.com`.

Most domain registrars are hosting provider can set this up for you.  Your hosting provider can be Google, or just about any other ISP/hosting provider out there.  You dont even have to have the website and the email hosted by the same provider.  However, having one provider does make life a little easier.

I do agree having an email associated with your domain is more professional.  While there is nothing inherently wrong with `mycompany@gmail.com`, some people will think you are a very small company.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do both?  Google offers this service:

https://apps.google.com/products/gmail/

EDIT: Or, are you saying you WANT to only use gmail?  In that case, bad idea - a company should have company email.