# Is first name only better than full name in e-mail address?

Tags: email

I have a choice to use first names instead of first and last name in professional e-mail addresses, for example:

john@mycompany.com

or

johndoe@mycompany.com

It would like to speed up communication by promoting less formal culture so I would like to go with the first name only: john@mycompany.com

Are there any drawbacks to that other than having two Johns in my company?

Comment: People could end up sending emails to "the wrong John".

Comment: As long as informality is desirable then the duplicate names problem is all you have to consider. As you take on more staff, do you have John1, John2, etc? My organisation is large and we already have john.doe2 !

Comment: How does johndoe@mycompany.com slow down communication? People have Contact lists.

Comment: @Taladris My concern is when trying to get subordinates to freely communicate with managers of their managers, whom they've never talked to, across hierarchy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should a professional email address look like?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/what-should-a-professional-email-address-look-like)

Comment: @gnat It's not a question whether it is professional. Both ways are professional and acceptable, but each may have small advantages/disadvantages that will add up when scaled across the entire company

Comment: I'd doubt the assumption less formal equals faster communication in general. And I fail to see a causal implication from the level of formality with respect to addressing someone to the level of formality in the actual content of communication. I think you're overthinking this and that you're overestimating the effects the naming of your mail addresses might have in this respect. The potential confusion from duplicates and doubt whether the mail address belongs to the "right" John will outweigh any benefit (if there is any at all) with regard to communication speed.

Comment: I go by Rob, on the entire Internet and offline (whenever possible), no one has yet said they've mistaken me for someone else. If the address is open grab it.

Comment: it's funny that **just first name** has, i would say, become the standard or preferred style.  (It's almost the case that, full name of "stevej" approach, signifies "very large company - unfortunately we have to add our surname!)  obviously, have both function as Erik mentions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to not just create both addresses, alias them together, and let people use whichever one they want. I'm sure you'll find cases where you *want* the extra formality of the full name address, and just as often you'll want the less formal one.

And in the cases where you don't care, just use the less formal one to promote that kind of atmosphere in the country.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. It might be a bit hard for a startup where each new e-mail has a considerable marginal cost. But surely there should be a hosting service out there for bundled up multiple e-mail addresses for a single user without additional cost

Comment: @ArthurTarasov I pay about $5 a month for unlimited email addresses, and that's just a consumer service. There really should be no extra cost to the number of email addresses your company has.

Comment: This makes it more confusing for people though. Is john@company the same as johndoe@company? Is it someone else? Is it a social engineering attempt? Also people might want to filter your mails and suddenly something breaks out of the filter. I'd advise against multiple mail addresses for inherently the same set of contacts. Maybe it's an approach if one is for internal and one for external communication although that distinction might also be hard to adhere to.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a couple of reasons why one is preferable to the other and they're about anonymity.

Information is currency, if there is no need for someone to know my last name, I don't give it. Not because I suspect everyone of a hidden agenda, but because it only takes ONE malicious person fishing for info to make a mess.

Pretty much the same with staff, it's not the individual that is important it is the job title, so many companies actually use the job title as email address. It also mitigates against people humanising their problems with your staff and nutcases building a personal grudge with an easily identifiable employee, or a competitor building a relationship and perhaps even making personal contact.

Similar issues along that vein, not something that would happen every day, but in a security conscious world and especially in a small country they need to be considered.