# What to do if i sent an e-mail with unprofessional name to a company that i applied to?

Tags: professionalism, internship, email

Recently I sent an e-mail that contains my resume to a company that I want to get my internship with. The problem is the e-mail name is not professional and goofy. Should I resend another e-mail using another account or just wait for their reply?

Comment: Have you also mentioned the same "goofy" email in your resume? Or did you just send it from the "goofy" email, while your resume has the "correct" email?

Comment: Personally I have stopped bothering about "goofy" email address from candidates unless it is something blatantly offensive like "allXareY" or "call4XXX" (I am not making this up!). I don't mind too much if the email is named after the candidate's favourite anime character. :)

Comment: You should not resend it. However, you should get another address for professional correspondence. Most (all?) email providers make creating an email alias connected to your account easy.

Comment: The main concern could be the company's spam filter, but that depends on the spam filter's settings and the nature of your address' goofiness. You could call the company (which is often a good idea for other reasons too).

Comment: @Thanos: My email address is a synonym for "screw up" (cfr my SO username). It's been my nickname for near 20 years online and in real life with all my friends, it has long surpassed its original meaning. Later in life, before I realized, my MCP certificates were attached to that account. And lo and behold, every company I've worked at since has had to see that account name. I know I could create an alias but effectively no one has cared about it one bit, other than noticing it is a personal address.

Answer (score 6):

Just wait for a reply.  The chances are that many interns also use informal email addresses for correspondence, so this wouldn't be entirely unexpected.  If the tone of your covering email is professional, this should be fine.

But yes, try to obtain a less goofy email address going forwards. Although many employers won't really mind, it comes across better when you give people your email address.

A good example of a professional-looking email address would be *firstname.lastname@mailprovider.com*

Also see [What should a professional email address look like?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/what-should-a-professional-email-address-look-like)

Comment: What would you propose if the person has a very common name? Not everyone can have the 'ideal' firstname.lastname email address.

Comment: @scotty3785 Do what everyone does: add middle name, initials, random numbers (**not** your age!). If you really care, buy a domain name.