# Does a custom email with top-level domain ".fyi" seem unprofessional?

Tags: professionalism, applications, email

Some time ago I've invested in my personal custom domain. No desirable variations of my name were available with a .com top-level domain so I went for .fyi instead. I like it - in my optinion its slightly playful but not obnoxious. My main email looks now something like `email@<MyName>.fyi`.

But before I start applying to jobs using that email I need to check whether my opinion of the harmlessness of my top-level domain is indeed justified. In your opinion, does using `email@<MyName>.fyi` in a job application seem unprofessional / silly / disrespectful?

This question is specifically about the top level domain as other similar questions seem to address primarily the email user name.

The industry is software engineering.

Comment: "F**k your intelligence" is a pretty odd choice for a custom domain TLD. :)

Comment: @MaskedMan That's not what it means. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FYI

Comment: @Belle-Sophie I'm sure MM is aware of that.  He was making a joke.

Comment: And perhaps making a point/hint on the possible interpretations of FYI and how it can be professional or unprofessional :) @Steve-O

Comment: ["No one will look twice at an email address that is used on a job application, unless it is something explicitly unsavory"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/11732) seems like a fine answer to this question, although I might've said "The vast majority of people", because some people definitely notice, but the effect should be very minor, and it could be either positive or negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it looks a little dodgy, expect people to ask if that's the correct email.

for job hunting, maybe just a Gmail address that directs to your FYI - or just a dedicated Gmail address.

the industry doesn't matter, its generally better to look like you confirm to normal standards when you meet people for the first time, and that includes your email.

Answer (score 2):

The whole thing is very very subjective, I can only tell my thoughts on it!

To mee it raises the question "why fyi?". com or your local country domain is neutral, a domain dealing with your website content or hobby is informative and can be funny, but what do you intend to express with fyi? Simply "there was noting else left" is not a good reason if you ever should explain this to someone.
It could express you believe to be more important than you really are.
Having your own domain with an empty website content adds to this thought. You should care about what is on this domain, employers probably will have a look on it.

If you have an interesting business or your website shows what you are able to do that helps in your new job, this is fine.
As a rule of thumb, you must not give the impression hey world, everyone has their own domain and so do I - but I have no idea what for. You can have this domain, that's no problem. But I'd use some neutral mailadress for serious things like a job application.

Comment: OP doesn't state that the domain contains a website. You can own a domain without ever using it for anything besides an email address. In fact, it was recommended a few years back that people should invest in a domain name with their own name so that someone else couldn't use if for nefarious purposes. But not too many people use their real name for website unless they are real professionals doing real business. In many cases though, having john@johnsmith.com is perfectly acceptable for an email address without ever having anything at johnsmith.com.